# cumulative weights in random.choices

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am confused using the new `random.choices` in Python 3.6.

Here is [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

> ```
> random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
> ```
>
> -- Return a *k* sized list of elements chosen from the *population* with replacement. If the *population* is empty, raises `IndexError`.

They give an example: `weights=[10, 5, 30, 5]` and I don't know what this means. Why don't they sum to 100? If my population is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` -- does this mean that a choice of '10' occurs with probability 0.1?

Comment: They don't sum to 100 because they're *relative* weights, not percentages. If the population doesn't include 10 the probability of it occurring is zero. In your example the probability of e.g. `1` is `10 / (10 + 5 + 30 + 5)`, or 0.2.

Comment: Aha. This clears things up! Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The total weight is 10+5+30+5=50.

Suppose the population is [1,2,3,4].

It returns 1 with probability 10/50 = 0.2

It returns 2 with probability 5/50 = 0.1

It returns 3 with probability 30/50 = 0.6

It returns 4 with probability 5/50 = 0.1

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense for relative weights. But what about cumulative weights? How is [10, 5, 30, 5] weights equivalent to [10, 15, 45, 50] cumulative weights?

Comment: cumulative weights is just the prefix sum of the weight by definition.